# How can I start a video from terminal

Tags: command-line, video, mac

I've been trying to make an executable file that maxes the volume of a person's computer then opens and plays a specific video, but I don't have a command to play the video after it has opened, so the video opens but the user has to click <kbd>play</kbd>.

Comment: Please try: `cvlc some_video.mp4`

Comment: Why the mac tag? Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: @Zanna I don't think Ubuntu on Mac supports airdrop, so not Ubuntu (see [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014008/how-can-i-start-a-video-from-terminal#comment1644569_1014015))

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

Try installing *mpv* and run your video like this in your script file:

```
mpv -fs myvideo.mp4
```

The *-fs* will make it go into full screen mode automatically.

Comment: but the thing is I'm trying to airdrop this to others as a joke (i know so immature) so it has to be a way that doesn't involve installing anything

Comment: Unless I misunderstand "airdropping", I guess what you want is execute your program on macOS. Then your question is just silly because not Ubuntu related.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to open and play the video just running the script...
Try `xdg-open video.mp4`, at least it works for me.